# Checking if an image is missing from folder in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a small slide show application to show images inside an html.

The name of images are something like:

- "MOD01_001.jpg"
- "MOD01_002.jpg"
- "MOD01_004.jpg" and so for...

Sometimes one or more images is missing and the previous images still is in the cache, so I can't check if the new image was loaded checking for the width/height properties.

What can I do to check if an images are missing from the list (I know I can't access the file info from inside client browser).
TIA

Comment: If you set `src` to an invalid URI (404 or not an image) it will fire the `error` event

Answer (score 0):

This loads them all in, so it could be really terrible:

```
var images = ['MOD01_001.jpg','MOD01_002.jpg','MOD01_003.jpg'];

for (i in images) {
  checkIfImageExists(images[i]);
}

function checkIfImageExists(image_path) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onerror = function(){
    console.log('Could not load image: ' + img.src);
  }
  img.onload = function(){
    console.log('Loaded image: ' + img.src);
  }

  img.src = image_path;
}
```